# Javascript setTimeOut function confusion

Tags: javascript

Hello can you explain me what is the difference between **setTimeOut(function, time)** and **setTimeOut(function(), time)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other two answers are correct, but just in case your question wasn't about anonymous functions but rather something like this

```
    function onTimeout(){
     console.log('foo');
    };

    setTimeout(onTimeout, 1000); // First form

    setTimeout(onTimeout(), 1000); // Second Form
```

The difference is that in the first form, the function onTimeout is called after 1 seconds, which is typically the desired outcome.

In the second form, on Timout is called immediately, and whatever that function returned is called after 1 seconds; in this case undefined would be called because console.log returns undefined. So the function would execute immediately and nothing would happen after 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, either you define the function and later you pass it as the first parameter of `setTimeout`:

```
function onTimeout() {

}

setTimeout(onTimeout, 3000);
```

...or you give an anonymous function as parameter as you call `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   // Do stuff
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following examples will explain the difference:

Calling a defined function on timeout.

```
setTimeout(my_function, 1000);

function my_function() {
    alert("Time is up!");
}
```

Calling an anonymous function on timeout.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Time is up!");
}, 1000);
```

The first example calls a function that is already defined while the other runs code as a anonymous function procedurally. I use both depending on the need.